# ion-img tag not showing online image url

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to show the image in ion-img tag from the internet but when I put the link in src or when I inspect, it shows only 30 chars from the URL, rest of the chars from the URL is not getting.

for eg:
url http://192.168.1.88/pg/profilepic/image.jpg

so when I inspect, it shows only

http://192.168.1.88/pg/profile

what is the problem..

I want to show in

```
<ion-list>
<button ion-item *ngFor="let item of data.result | filter : searchText" [navPush]="pushPage" [navParams]="{id:item.id}">
  <ion-img src="http://192.168.1.88/pg/profilepic/image.jpg"></ion-img>
  {{item.name}}
  <div class="item-note" item-end>
    {{item.desc}}
  </div>
</button>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: @Kirubel updated

Comment: I think the problem is with ur `src` path. Can you try using from google images.
And do something like 
`<ion-img src="http://192.168.1.88/pg/profilepic/image.jpg" width="200px" height="200px"></ion-img>

Comment: does it work with `img` instead of `ion-img`?

Comment: It should work with both

Comment: @Kirubel `ion-img` is used with virtual scroll.. could be a factor

Comment: Yes it works with the img tag but not with ion-img.. i want it to be shown in the ion-img tag

Answer (score 1):

Realize this is an old(ish) question. But I ran into the same problem recently.

I believe it is not using the virtual scroll like Suraj Rao said.

The following worked for me

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="itemsArray">
   <ion-item *virtualItem="let item">
     <ion-img [src]="item.url"></ion-img>
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Where itemsArray is an array, and item is an element of that array with a url property.

In your case, I'd try

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="data.result | filter : searchText">
<button ion-item *virtualItem="let item" [navPush]="pushPage [navParams]="{id:item.id}">
  <ion-img src="http://192.168.1.88/pg/profilepic/image.jpg"></ion-img>
  {{item.name}}
  <div class="item-note" item-end>
    {{item.desc}}
  </div>
</button>
```

Sources

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/img/Img/
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/